# Get only significant data from nested lists

Tags: list, grails, groovy, many-to-one

Hi! I want to get only the significant information (complete flow) of a download link.

I have my domain designed something like this:

```js
Serie { hasMany[Season] }
Season { hasMany[Episode] and belongsTo[Serie] }
Episode { hasMany[DownloadInfo] and belongsTo[Season] }
DownloadInfo { link nullable:true //among other data }
```

And I have in my DB approximately this number of records:

```js
serie:4500
season:500
episode:6500
download_info:10000
```

We can see that there are a lot of series without other information.

**How can I get only those series>season>episode>downloadInfo data only where all of these are completed?**

For example, having:

```js
Serie "A"
  Season "sA1"
Serie "B"
  Season "sB1"
    Episode "eB1"
      Link "b1.1"
      Link "b1.2"
    Episode "eB2"
    Episode "eB3"
      Link "b3.1"
Serie "C"
  Season "sC1"
    Episode "eC1"
Serie "D"
Serie "E"
  Season "sE1"
    Episode "eE1"
      Link "e1.1"
  Season "sE2"
    Episode "eE2"
      Link "e2.1"
```

I want to get this:

```js
def model = [series:[
  name:'B',
  seasons:[
    name:'sB1',
    episodes:[
      name:'eB1',
      links:['b1.1','b1.2']
    ],[
      name:'eB3',
      links:['b3.1']
    ]
  ]
],[
  name:'E'
  seasons:[
    name:'sE1',
    episodes:[
      name:'eE1',
      links:['e1.1']
    ]
  ],[
    name:'sE2'
    episodes:[
      name:'eE2',
      links:['e2.1']
    ]
  ]
]
```

**Discarding all Series, Seasons Episodes and DownloadInfo that has no link.**

BTW, I need only the DownloadInfo where link property is not null.
I started with:

```js
DownloadInfo.where { link!= null }.list().each {
  // ...
}
```

But I can't figure out an elegant way to do all the flow. Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

**Updated**

It would be the Groovy's equivalent to the following SQL, grouped by name of each entity:

```sql
select * from serie s
inner join season ss on s.id = ss.serie_id
inner join episode e on ss.id = e.season_id
inner join download_info di on e.id = di.episode_id
where di.link is not null
```